# Copying and renaming tab VBA

Tags: excel, vba

VBA newbie, I am trying to find a way to increase the number of tabs or sheets by copying the last one and then renumbering it. i.e copying tab 150 then relabeling it 151 and so on.

I've figured out a way to copy the sheet with the code below:

```
Sub CopySheetRename1()
 
Sheets("150").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "LastSheet"
 
End Sub
```

But i can't get the new sheet to rename itself.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: That code works for me.

Comment: Yes, i can get it to work, but it doesn't automatically change to the name of the new worksheet to the next number.

Comment: Check my answer for a solution .below

Comment: Well you renamed it "LastSheet" Do you want it to rename it 151?

Comment: Feel free to accept a helpful answer by ticking the green checkmark, so you'll help other users, too looking for (best) solutions - @NodnarB321

Answer (score 1):

This perhaps. It's not clear if you have only sheets numbered or others.

```
Sub CopySheetRename1()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
ws.Copy After:=ws
If IsNumeric(ws.Name) Then ActiveSheet.Name = CLng(ws.Name) + 1
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Sub Loadsoftabscreations() 'as many as you want :)
 
Worksheets("Sheet150").Select

For x = 1 To 300 ' or as many new fresh tabs you want

Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "YourTab - " & x

Next x
End Sub
```

You can set the names in the code as you want.

as per my comment, for copying x number of times:

```
Sub LoadsoftabscreationsC()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

For x = 1 To 10 ' or as many as needed

ws.Copy After:=ws
If IsNumeric(ws.Name) Then Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name

Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: This works, but doesn't copy the data contained Sheet 150

Comment: sorry, i missunderstood. below my first answer is another one using part of SJR's where the last sheet in the sheet is copied x number of times. just added out of completion on my side.

Comment: perfect! Thanks for the help